# Is there a way to insert columns at specific indices using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have done it with a sort-of brute force method (below), but is there a way to do this with maybe making one dictionary and utilizing a pandas function or something? There has to be a cleaner way to do this. I know you can just add these columns as you create them but I need them to be in a specific order.

```
# Notice there are missing indices from the lists because those are already occupied by other columns
new_col_names = ['col1',
    'col2',
    'col3',
    'col4',
    'col5',
    'col7',
    'col9',
    'col10',
    'col11',
    'col12',
    'col15',
    'col17',
    'col18',
    'col19',
    'col20',
    'col21',
    'col22',
    'col23',
    'col24',
    'col25',
    'col26',
    'col31',
    'col32',
]
indexes_to_append = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32]

for i in range(len(new_col_names)):
    dataframe.insert(loc=indexes_to_append[i], column=new_col_names[i], value=pd.NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `reindex` by a complete list of columns. An example using 10 cols for readability:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[6, 8]], 
                  columns=['col6', 'col8'])

print(df)
   col6  col8
0     6     8

cols = [f'col{x}' for x in range(1, 11)]

print(cols)
['col1',
 'col2',
 'col3',
 'col4',
 'col5',
 'col6',
 'col7',
 'col8',
 'col9',
 'col10']

df = df.reindex(cols, axis=1)
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10
0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     6   NaN     8   NaN    NaN
```